# SSRS report, want to display row based on values within row

Tags: ssrs-2008, multiple-columns

My report essentially compares two templates. I have two columns one for template a and one for template b. Then I have about 200 unique rows(fields/properties of templates).

```
Fields   templateA    templateB
 Cass         1           1
 Foreign      1           0
 Vacant       0           0
 APO/FPO      32
```

What I want to do is only display rows where thier are different values for template a and b, like Foreign and APO.
I know I can use individual row display to get them to hide. However writing this for 200 individual rows would be rediculous and I may need to repeat this task in the future.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cant do it by filtering your tablix.

Right click on the tablix, click on `tablix properties`.

under `Filter` tab,  add new filter rule, and define the following:

**Expression**: `templateA`

**Operator**: `<>`

**Value**: `templateB`